# Published article on Arxiv: Elsevier Gold Open Access

Tags: publications, arxiv, license, elsevier

Am I allowed to publish the final manuscript PDF (as it is in the journal) on Arxiv if the paper is published as "Gold Open Access" in an Elsevier journal?

Comment: Ask Elsevier, but I'd think they have rules against it. What is the point? It complicates citation to some extent.

Comment: @Buffy How does an arXiv posting of a published paper complicate citations in any way at all?

Comment: @E.P., some people will see one and some will see the other. Depending on how they cite, they won't be unified.

Comment: @Buffy Obviously OP should be diligent in providing full metadata at the time of upload to arXiv, in which case the full journal link is added to the arXiv abstract page. Any readers who find the arXiv version and fail to discover the canonical journal reference are, to be frank, hopelessly clueless. arXiv has worked just fine, on this basis, for decades. This is a non-problem.

Comment: @p.egli The answer seems to be "it depends", as the Elsevier offerings seem to include multiple choices of end-user license for authors. Have you chosen one already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes, with reservations](https://www.elsevier.com/about/policies/sharing).

> [Gold open access articles] May be shared according to the author-selected end-user license and should contain a CrossMark logo, the end user license, and a DOI link to the formal publication on ScienceDirect.

Comment: IANAL, but I don't think that they can legally enforce these 'reservations'. Copyright remains with you, and especially if you chose a CC license with your open-access option this kind of additional restrictions is usually explicitly forbidden.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I believe these are not "reservations" but guidance regarding attribution. Note that Elsevier has copyright regarding the typesetting / layout. They can require attribution for their derivative work.